# python error: generator object P at 0x02DAC198

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.4.* and I am trying to execute the following code:

```
def P(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield []
        return

    for p in P(n-1):        
        p.append(1)
        yield p
        p.pop()
        if p and (len(p) < 2 or p[-2] > p[-1]):
            p[-1] += 1
            yield p


print(P(5))   # this line doesn't make sense


for i in P(5):   # but this line does make sense thanks to furkle 
    print(i)
```

but I am getting `<generator object P at 0x02DAC198>` rather than the output.

Can someone explain where in my code needs to be fixed? I don't think py likes the function name P but I could be wrong.

Edit: furkle clarified `<generator object P at 0x02DAC198>`.

By the way, I'm currently trying to write my own modified partition function and I was trying to understand this one corresponding to the classical setting.

Comment: Your code is *working as designed*. There is no error here, you produced a generator function because you used `yield`. What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Using `list(P(5))` will give you the empty list back, but my guess is that's not really what you want to see, either...

Comment: I think this is the first post-modifying generator I've seen. It yields lists that aren't empty, then empties them if you keep reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the concept of a generator. A generator object is like a list, but you can iterate through its results lazily, without having to wait for the whole list to be constructed. Calling an operation on a function that returns a generator will not perform that operation in sequence on every item yielded by the generator.

If you wanted to print all the output of P(5), you should write:

```
for i in P(5):
    print(i)
```

If you just want to print a list of the content returned by the generator, that largely seems to defeat the purpose of the generator.

Answer (score 1):

Many things are wrong with this code, and your understanding of how generators work and what they are used for.

First, with respect to your `print` statement, that is exactly what it should print. Generators are *never* implicitly expanded, because there is no guarantee that a generator would ever terminate. It's perfectly valid, and sometimes very desirable, to construct a generator that produces an endless sequence. To get what you'd want (which I assume is produce output similar to a list), you'd do:

```
print(list(P(5))
```

But that brings me to my second point; Generators *yield values in a sequence* (in 99% of uses for them, unless you're using it as a coroutine). You are trying to use your generator to construct a list; however, if `n` is not `0` this will never *yield* a value and will immediately return. If you goal is to construct a generator that makes a list of `1`'s of a given length, it should look like this:

```
def P(n):
    while n >= 0:
        yield n
        n -=1
```

This will produce a sequence of 1's of length `n`. To get the list form, you'd do `list(P(n))`.

I suggest you have another read over the [Generator Documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and get a better feel for them and see if they're really the right tool for the job.

Comment: @MeeSeong no problem. Note that for generating a sequence of 1's, `[1 for _i in range(n+1)]` will be much more efficient. I just provided the generator example because that's what you were asking about.

Answer (score 0):

In reading the function, I try to find what the call will produce. Let's start with the full original code:

```
def P(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield []
        return

    for p in P(n-1):        
        p.append(1)
        yield p
        p.pop()
        if p and (len(p) < 2 or p[-2] > p[-1]):
            p[-1] += 1
            yield p


print(P(5))   # this line doesn't make sense
```

Okay, so it calls `P(5)`. Since that's not 0, P recurses, until we reach `P(0)` which yields an empty list. That's the first time `p` receives a value. Then `P(1)` appends `1` into that list, and yields it to `P(2)` which repeats the process.. and so on. All the same list, originally created by `P(0)`, and eventually yielded out as `[1,1,1,1,1]` by `P(5)` - but then the magic happens. Let's call this first list `l0`.

When you ask the generator for the second item, control returns to `P(5)` which now removes a value from `l0`. Depending on a bunch of conditions, it may increment the last value and yield `p`, which is `l0`, again. So the first item we received has been changing while we asked for the second. This will eventually terminate, but means there's a difference between these two:

```
print list(P(5))  # Eventually prints a list of l0 which has been emptied!
for item in P(5):
    print item    # Prints l0 at each point it was yielded

In [225]: for i in P(5): print i
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 1]
[3, 2]
[4, 1]
[5]

In [226]: list(P(5))
Out[226]: [[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

This is why I called it post-modifying; the values it returns keep changing after they've been produced (since they are in fact the same object being manipulated).